# How to add an alias without directly editing the `bash_aliases` file?

Tags: bash, alias, profile

Is there a way to add an alias from the command line without directly editing the bash_aliases file? To clarify, how can I make a bash script do it without having to enter something along the lines of `nano bash_aliases` to add them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash_aliases` (it is not necessary, you can also have aliases defined in `.bashrc` among other places), you can simply add a line to the file:

```
printf "alias foo='bar'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

Alternatively, if you only want this alias for the current session, use the alias command directly:

```
alias foo='bar'
```

#### Important

Bash does not allow aliases to be expanded (to work) in scripts by default, you will need to activate the `expand_aliases` option:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

alias foo='echo "It works!"'
echo "  Alias defined, attempting to use without expand_aliases"
foo

shopt -s expand_aliases
echo "  Attempting to use with expand_aliases"
foo
```

If I run the script above, the alias `foo` will only work after I have activated the `expand_aliases` option:

```
$ a.sh
  Alias defined, attempting to use without expand_aliases
/home/terdon/scripts/a.sh: line 5: foo: command not found
  Attempting to use with expand_aliases
It works!
```

Comment: so if I run `shopt -s expand_aliases`, is it permanent? As long as I don't totally reinstall the OS, it'll stay? I ask because I'm on a Raspberry Pi; some things reset when I reboot.

Comment: Also, to confirm, if I just use the alias command, it will also reset once I reboot?

Comment: @evamvid no, it will only work for the particular session. What are you trying to do? Is this something you want to do once in a script? Everytime you boot? Do you want the alias to be available to the script? In the normal session? Please explain what your end objective is.

Comment: I'm trying to set up a node.js blogging platform called Ghost on my Pi. It has a pretty long, fiddly command to start up in production mode. I wanted to make an alias so that I could just put in `startghost` for it to start.

Comment: It looks like it might just be easier for me to have a startghost script that will start it up.

Comment: @evamvid I don't understand. Just manually edit `bash_aliases` once, add the relevant alias and you're done, it will be available for ever. You don't need to do this on each boot. What would the script be for?

Comment: ohhhhhh..............  =) I got confused and started overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 1):

Just execute the alias as you would in bash_alias.

```
alias lt='ls -altrch'
```

Check by using type command.

```
type alias
lt is aliased to 'ls -altrch'
```

Comment: Whoa! You can do that?  =)

Comment: Note that this will not work in a script unless you activate `expand_aliases`, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [HEREDOCS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to add multiple lines as well:

```
(
cat <<EOF
alias ali1='cmds1...'
alias ali2='cmds2...'
EOF
) >> ~/bash_aliases
```

The above can be copy pasted into a shell.

#### Results

```
$ more ~/bash_aliases 
alias ali1='cmds1...'
alias ali2='cmds2...'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just make a new script to do the startup. Create a file, /usr/local/bin/start_node_blog with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

that_long_fiddly_command_you_mentioned
```

Then do

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start_node_blog
```

and you can run it after a reboot.